# How to fix an hover property not spanning on the whole grid element?

Tags: css, hover, css-grid

I am using CSS grid for my navigation bar, but I get a bug when coding the hover on the links... The change of background colour does not spread on the entire grid element.

I have used the property `align-self: stretch` to fix this, but this still does not work...

Here is the header HTML:

```
<body>
<header>
    <a href="./index.html" title="Welcome" class="logo"><img src="img/logo_jaeaess_glitch.png" alt="Logo of the VJ Jääß (Jess de Jesus)" style="width:42px;height:42px"></a>
    <nav>
        <a href="./index.html" title="Welcome" class="welcome active">Welcome</a>
        <a href="./about.html" title="About" class="about">About</a>
        <a href="./artwork.html" title="Art Work" class="artwork">Art Work</a>
        <a href="./events.html" title="Events" class="events">Events</a>
    </nav>
</header>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

nav {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    justify-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}

nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--neonpink);
}

nav a:hover {
    background: var(--yellow);
    align-self: stretch;
    justify-self: stretch;
    text-align: center;
}
```

It almost work, except that just 2 lines, one on top, one under the link, remain turquoise...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhYf2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the alignment you have in the `nav` element...that seems *off*.

Try it on the link instead

```css
header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

nav a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  background: #000;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

nav a:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <a href="#" title="Welcome" class="logo"><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" alt="Logo of the VJ Jääß (Jess de Jesus)" style="width:42px;height:42px"></a>
    <nav>
      <a href="./index.html" title="Welcome" class="welcome active">Welcome</a>
      <a href="./about.html" title="About" class="about">About</a>
      <a href="./artwork.html" title="Art Work" class="artwork">Art Work</a>
      <a href="./events.html" title="Events" class="events">Events</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Paulie_D ! It worked indeed, I still don't understand completely why a flex was needed, but this is probably because I am much more familiar with grid than flex.
I followed your solution and wrote this:
`
nav {
    justify-items: center;
}

nav a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--neonpink);
}
nav a:hover {
    background: var(--yellow);
    justify-self: stretch;
}
`